# How to run a powershell files in parallel by calling it from another powershell file?

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have File1.ps1 which needs to call File2.ps1 and File3.ps1 in parallel,they must open in different windows. Any ideas of how I might accomplish this?

start-process and other commandlets dont seem to work.

Comment: Try using the jobs system.  See a good example [here](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2014/04/11/parallel-processing-in-powershell.aspx).

Comment: How exactly Start-Process doesn't work? Example: `Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList @("-NoExit", "-Command", "File2.ps1")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up each file to execute with a scheduled task to start at the same time.  I've tested it and found that the two windows come up and execute at the same time.

```
$filePath = "C:\path\to\files"
$fileList = ".\File2.ps1", ".\File3.ps1"
$startTime = (get-date).AddMinutes(1)

foreach ($file in $fileList) {
    Register-ScheduledTask `
        -Trigger (New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At $startTime) `
        -Action (new-scheduledtaskaction -execute "powershell.exe" -argument "-noexit -file $filePath\$($file.TrimStart('.\'))") `
        -TaskName "Execute-$($file.Split(".\")[2])" `
        -TaskPath Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs `
        -Principal (New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -LogonType Interactive -UserId $env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME -RunLevel Highest)

}
```

Comment: but would'nt start-process run them sequentially and not in parallel?

Comment: @user3325210 I revised my answer.  You are correct in that the original answer I posted would execute each start-process sequentially.